# C# WPF Twitch can anyone point me in a direction for video inside an app?

Tags: c#, wpf, http-live-streaming, twitch

Hello I am working on developing a basic C# WPF app that uses the API to get information about the user and display useful data. However, the only main reason someone would want to use this kind of application would be to watch video as well. Can anyone suggest methods for playing Twitch live streams inside the application? Possible methods would be the webbrowser control, or mediaelement. Thank you for your time.

Comment: "Possible methods would be the webbrowser control, or mediaelement." You just answered your question, I guess. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: My mediaelement is blank, and the webbrowser control has script errors then never loads. So I don't understand how to implement them I suppose.

Comment: Are there some crazy workarounds that my application uses livestreamer and then uses that information from that? Or some workaround that I use VLC with my application?

Comment: If you want to show twitch streams - first get their url via twitch api (https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API).